# creating tooltip for dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can anyone tell how to add tooltip for dynamically created button.In my page i have one submit button,and it will create dynamic buttons with respect to the xml data.i want to create tooltip for this buttons.here is my code

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Submit").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "mars.xml",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function (xml) {
                            $(xml).find('student').each(function () {
                                var Name = $(this).find('name').text();
                                var Mark = $(this).find('marks').text();
                                var Sid = $(this).find('id').text();
                var student_id = "#"+$(this).attr("id");
 $("#content").append("<li><input type='button' class='dyna_btn' id = '"+$(this).attr("id")+"' value='"+Name+"'/></li>");
                    var hue = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);

                    $(student_id).css('color', hue);
                    $("#content").append('<li>' + Sid + '<li>');
                         });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            $(document).on("click", ".dyna_btn", function() {
                     alert("button"+$(this).attr("id"));
                     console.log("button clicked");
                      });
         </script>
        <body>
        <form id="From1" method="post">
        <input type="button" value="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" />
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add title="" attribute in same way like this:

```
<input type='button' class='dyna_btn' id = '"+$(this).attr("id")+"' value='"+Name+"' title='"+Name+"' />
```